# How to spawn object over network as child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I'm having an issue where I'm trying to spawn an object for all players into a scroll view. On the host, they get spawned properly, but on the remote clients that have joined, the objects are just placed into the hierarchy.

I'm using NetworkServer.Spawn to do so, and I can't seem to find a solution.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Have you added a `NetworkTransform`?

Comment: Hello @Thomas!

Can you plase update the queastion with the answer? I am not able to figure out how to spawn child objects.

Answer (score -1):

In the Unity Docs, it states the parameters of NetworkServer.spawn.

> **Parameters**
>
> **obj**   - Game object with **NetworkIdentity** to spawn.

I'm going to go on a limb here and say that you don't have a Network Identity on your object, which is why it spawns in your host but not in your remote clients.

Either that or as @DanRayson stated...you don't have a Network Transform.

Comment: This is not my problem. I'm talking about them not spawning as a child of another object. The problem is that they spawn outside of any GameObjects, not that they don't spawn altogether...

Comment: Does the parent object have a NetworkIdentity or Network Transform?

Comment: Don't worry I fixed it. But yeah it does.